# Why is sys.stdout.write outputs unexpected characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
temp=1
stdout.write(str(temp))
```

I am expecting output to be 1 but it is 11 . Why?

Comment: The problem is likely to be the lack of newline and that at some earlier or later point in your code another `1` is being written. If you want to write a newline, then you have to do so explicitly, e.g. `sys.stdout.write(str(temp) + '\n')`, unlike with `print()`.

Comment: if I go with sys.stdout.write(str(temp)+'\n') then output is  1   2.I only want 1 as a output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys.stdout.write)

Help on built-in function write:

write(text, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Write string to stream.
    Returns the number of characters written (which is always equal to
    the length of the string)
```

The first `"1"` is the argument that you give to `write` and the second `"1"` is length of your string returned by `write`.

```
>>> sys.stdout.write("Hello")
Hello5
```

Note that the return value appears in the output because this is an interactive session. If you run this code from a `.py` file, you would only see `"Hello"`, as you expected.